# Windows Store App - remove fullTrustCapability

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a C++-Win32-app which should be deployed in the Microsoft Store. Unfortunately, since `runFullTrust`is added automatically as required capability, the program appears in Microsoft Store as follows: "This app can access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs and registry.", but I don't need all of those capabilities. Is there any possibility to get rid of the `runFullTrust` capability or to choose which capabilities are really needed?

Comment: No. If you want fine-grained access control, you'll need to target a platform that supports fine-grained access control, like the Universal Windows Platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to publish the Win32 apps in Microsoft Store, and you must add restricted capability **runFullTrust** in the manifest.

Only UWP app can be published in the Microsoft Store,if you have an existing desktop application that was built using the .NET Framework (including WPF and Windows Forms) or C++ Win32 APIs, you can several options(Package your desktop application in an MSIX package, Use UWP APIs...) for moving to the UWP and Windows 10. The moved app called desktop bridge apps. You can see more details in document:
[Move from a desktop application to UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-migrate)

The restricted capability runFullTrust is required for any desktop application that is delivered as an appx or msix package (as with the Desktop Bridge), and it will automatically appear in your manifest when packaging these apps using the Desktop App Converter (DAC) or Visual Studio. You can see this in document:
[Restricted capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities)